# CNN classified only one variable if it is true or false

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, classification

So i was trying to make a voice classifier, the challenge was to predict if the person talking is me or is other person, i already build a simple code that converts .wav file into an array, so all my datasets of audio files of me talking will be converted into arrays, the thing is that I am a beginner and i dont know how to only use one variable for predicting(my voice), is like saying true or false, how can i make a neural network(CNN) that works like that?

Or should i use another type of machine learning? And not deep learning? I would like to use deep learning for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Because it seems that you are relatively new to the topic, I would propose that you start with an easier machine learning model for this simple classification task. Maybe for the first model a Logistic Regression could be enough.

So, you say you collected some samples of your own voice (your positve class), but did you also collect some negative samples from other people?

After this, I would suggest to chunk the converted samples into equal siced sequences and label them (your voice or another?).

Now with this as basis, you can test some easier models like the Logistic Regression or the KNN. You then might move forward to some simple Feed-Forward-Neural-Networks and then go on to some advanced models like CNN's or RNN's.

Comment: Well im not that begginer, i have already done regression, KNN, logistic linear models, and also stock prediction model using RNN, and face detection with CNN, but yes, there is only in my data my voice, not another, can it be made only with one variable(my voice), and if is not similar to my voice or if the acc is very low say its false?, how can i do that?

Comment: Ah okay, now I understand better what you want to achieve. So I would say it is more an Outlier Detection than a Classification. For this, Autoencoder seems to be a good approach. I haven‘t done this by myself, but this thread might help you: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19357/detecting-anomalies-with-neural-network